# How to prevent users from accessing list defaultview via url?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

In order to prevent users from being able to see all items of a list, we are displaying list via a list view webpart with filter as ColumnName=[Me]. However, users can access the list via the URL and get the default view.

How to prevent users from accessing list defaultview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is built in `Item Level Permissions` settings that allows to specify which items users are allowed to read/create/update

To grant item level permissions, follow these steps:

- Navigate to the site that contains the list, and open the list or
  library.
- Choose the List tab.
- On the ribbon, select Settings and then select Advanced settings.
- On the Advanced settings, specify corresponding permission settings.

[image]

Refer [Edit permissions for a list, library, or individual item](http://office.microsoft.com/client/15/help/home?Shownav=true&lcid=1033&ns=SPOSTANDARD&helpID=ItemLevelPermissions&ver=16&services=OFFICESUBSCRIPTION,MCOSTANDARD,EXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE,SHAREPOINTWAC_DEVELOPER,SHAREPOINT_S_DEVELOPER) for more details

Answer (score 3):

You can set the view that you have configured as the default view, and then delete the allitems.aspx view. That way when people navigate to the list they are taken to the new default view (your view).

It is important to be aware though that this is no substitute for security. Users will stil be able to access individual list items by their unique url, and if users have access to create their own views then people will easily be able to work around this.

If security is critical within this list, you will need to manage permissions to each list item individually, which can get very messy. However, there are alternative code solutions that you could try.

Hope this helps